# Excel 2016 - How to bring up a conditional list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to create a dependent list in Excel 2016, but don't really know where to start. I tried following a couple of guides to create a dependent list, but it wasn't doing what I wanted it to do.

So I've got the below sheet:

[Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3alXt.jpg)

In Cell B2, I've got a drop down list, the values are from cells G2 to I2.

Here is the list action:

[Drop down list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANcOk.jpg)

I created this list by making cells G2 to I2 into a table, then using data validation in cell B2 into a list, which calls on the table.

Here is the table details I put in:

[Table Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaOfN.jpg)

What I'd like, is that when I select from the drop down list in B2, the cell in A7 then brings up the correlating list. For example, if I select Red team in B2, I'd like a drop down list containing Fred, John and Marge to show. If I select Green team, I'd like James, Emma and Elizabeth to show.

What's the best way that I can do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use the `switch` formula in A7 that looks at C2 then gives the team members depending on which team shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Rename teams to a one-word name (Red or Red_Team or RedTeam) in range G2:I2
2. Create new Named Ranges for teams with the same name as is above (e.g. Name "RedTeam", range "G3:G5")
3. For a cell A7 create a Data validation as a list and the formula is:

```
=INDIRECT(B2)
```

[image: Working solution]

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly how I did it, funnily enough I was typing the solution as you posted that. The advice was spot on

Answer (score 0):

Switch didn't do what I wanted it to, however with some more googling and playing around, I found a way.
Rather than using tables, I just selected each list, then clicked 'Define Name' to create a name for each list, and a name for the main lists (the team names).

I then used the Data Validation (List) on the first drop down list.

For the second, the dependent list, I used the INDIRECT function, pointing at the first drop down list. As long as the names of the lists matched the headers of the lists, everything works as it should.